# How do I get Apigility to not return 406 when no Accept-Type is specified in the request

Tags: android, imageview, titanium-mobile, content-type, laminas-api-tools

I have an Titanium Android app that displays images from URLs. I would like to use apigilty to serve these images.

I have a stream response RPC service which works when called from a browser. However on android it does not work as it appears the android `ImageView` does not send a `Accept-Type` header and Apigiilty rejects the call with a `406 - Cannot honor Accept type specified`.

Is there a way I can configure my apigility project to ignore the `Accept-Type` check just for this RPC service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Accept` header of the incoming request is checked inside the  [`ZF\ContentNegotiationAcceptFilterListener`](https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-content-negotiation/blob/master/src/AcceptFilterListener.php) class and if no accept header is present [the `validateMediaType` method returns `false`](https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-content-negotiation/blob/master/src/AcceptFilterListener.php#L78) and then the `ApiProblemResponse` is created [at line 55](https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-content-negotiation/blob/master/src/AcceptFilterListener.php#L55).

The best would of course be to make sure that you get an accept header inside all your requests, but in case this is somehow impossible you could set a default accept header inside all your requests.

You can simply solve it by adding this in your application `Module.php` method:

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $event)
{
    $application    = $event>getApplication();
    $eventManager   = $application->getEventManager();

    // Attach setDefaultAcceptHeader method with higher priority then AcceptFilterListener
    $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, [$this, 'setDefaultAcceptHeader'], 100);
}

/**
 * @var MvcEvent $event
 */
public function setDefaultAcceptHeader(MvcEvent $event)
{
    $request = $event->getRequest();

    if( ! $request instanceof \Zend\Http\Request){
        // Not a http request, return
        return;
    }
    // Check if we have an accept header, if not set to 'application/json'
    $headers = $request->getHeaders();
    if(!$headers->has('accept')){
        $headers->addHeaderLine('accept', 'application/json');
    }
}
```